# I have a problem in my search method for the arraylist. The condition is true only in the first index

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the initialazation of array. I already have the get and set method which is already functional. My problem is example i use my addStudent method then i put three names. Only the first student i inputted will be true else is false

```
static ArrayList<Dynamic> users = new ArrayList<Dynamic>();
```

This is my method for search

```
public static void searchStudent() {
        String trash= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter First Name");
        String find = in.nextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {
        if(find.equalsIgnoreCase(users.get(i).getfName())){
                System.out.println("Student is Found");
                System.out.println(users.get(i));
                menu();
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Student Not found");
            menu();
        }
        }
    }//end of searchStudent
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. When the current student is the one you serch for, you know it's in the list, and you can exit the loop. But when the current student is NOT the one you search for, then you can't say that it isn't in the list: it might be the next one. You can only know once the loop has finished. If you indented your code properly, the structure of the code would be clear, and you would notice that kind of bug much more easily.

Comment: What is your goal ? Find just all names in users array or wanna find names with indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code will print "Student is Found" only when the student is the first element in the ArrayList. To make it search in the whole list, get the code in else block out of the loop.

```
public static void searchStudent() {
        String trash= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter First Name");
        String find = in.nextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {
            if(find.equalsIgnoreCase(users.get(i).getfName())){
                System.out.println("Student is Found");
                System.out.println(users.get(i));
                menu();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Student Not found");
        menu();
}//end of searchStudent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void searchStudent() {
        String trash= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter First Name");
        String find = in.nextLine();
        boolean found = false; 

        for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {
            if(find.equals(users.get(i).getfName())){
                System.out.println("Student is Found");
                System.out.println(users.get(i));
                found = true;
                menu();
            }
        }
        if(found == false){
             System.out.println("Student Not found");
        menu();

        }
    }
```